# Entity Framework and DataSet.WriteXml()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In the past I have some code that works with datasets that are persisted to disk using XML. Is there an EF provider that would allow me to use EF where the "back end" is XML rather than SQLExpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't. Linq to xml is very handy but you would have to roll your own models and abstraction to the xml files. I just heard that EF7 will have support for other types of data sources, but I'm not sure if xml is one of them.